# VS Code launch.json, debug with input user

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suppose I have in working directory hundreds exe file, I would like to debug one of them.
I do not want that launch.json will have hundreds objects for each exe file.

Is there a way, to have one object, and when start debug, I will choose which file I would like to debug?

I have tried extension "VSCode Prompt Debug" but it seems it does not work

In VSCode there is inputs, how can I use regex
for example:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${input:pickProgram}"
  }],
  "inputs": [{
      "id": "pickProgram",
      "description": "Select client or server",
      "type": "pickString",
      "options": ["*.exe"]
  }]}
```

Thanks